# Enable Http or Https requests in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-7.5

I have many applications resides under the same site in my IIS. I want to configure some of them to work only with http and others in https . The whole site can decide for all of them to work with http or all with https.

How I can manage that ?
Thanks in advance ...

Comment: you have to configure each one of them individually to use ssl certificate.

Comment: But I need to forbid http request for some apps under the same site , and I see no option to make on of them for each app.

Comment: you have to write one http module and check the request for each app, if request is unsecure for that request, change the request protocol to https and port number to 443

Answer (score 0):

IIS changes for https:

- Go to → My Web Application → require SSL → enable the SSL to enforce only https. If this is not forced than use can connect via both https and http.
- Optionally we can add a Http response header in IIS to force https download of any resource if request via normal http url
  Note: after enabling above header we force user to access via only http